# Skype for Business 2015 - Enable AD users

Tags: lync, skype, skype-for-business-2016

I have installed Skype for Business 2015 into a test lab environment and am now struggling enabling any users.

I have created three new AD users - `U1@test.local`, `U2@test.local` and `U3@test.local`.

When I load up the Skype Console and select USERS none of the above users are displayed in the search results (in fact no users at all appear) and all the actions are grayed out.

I would be extremely grateful for any ideas as I have absolutely hit a dead end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're seeing two different issues. If the user you are using to access the Skype for Business Control Panel does not have the correct permissions, you will not be able to perform the desired actions. You want to ensure this user account belong to the following groups:

```
CSAdministrator
CSUserAdministrator
RTCUniversalServerAdmins
RTCUniversalUserAdmins
RTCUniversalReadOnlyAdmins
```

After you ensure proper permissions, log out and log back in. In the Skype for Business Control Panel, when you click Users, then Find, you are searching for Skype For Business-enabled users, of which you currently have none. You would have to click "Enable Users", then "add", then "Find". From here, you will see the AD users you created, and can then enable them.

Comment: The account I am using to login to O365 Skype for Business Control panel is a global admin in O365 (which I presume means I am in the above groups, but even if not, all the groups I seem to be able to add anyone to are unique AD groups, nothing starting with the first 3 letters of any of the above; Also that as a global admin that I don't need to add any other permissions that are available under "customized administrator"), but I am also missing the Enable Users options which I believe is preventing me from enabling half my company.

Answer (score 0):

The user used to administer Skype via the Skype Console needs to be a member of the `CSUserAdministrator` group - even is already a member of `CSAdministrator`